# Search for a non-unicode characters in a file

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I have a block of text(an extract from db) and I would like to find the non-unicode characters because at some part of the code(`python 3.6`) when I'm converting the values into `str` I get the following `ValueError: character U+ffffffc2 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]`

So If I can find the non-unicode characters, I can decide what to do with them. I definitely don't want to replace them with something else.

I found how to find non-ascii chars in a file  with `grep --color='auto' -P -n '[^\x00-\x7F]' file_name.txt` but I'm not sure if this gives me the non-unicode chars also.

Answer (score 0):

See http://p3rl.org/Encode#coderef-for-CHECK

```
# contains U+ffffffc2 encoded in UTF-8
› hex nonunicodefile
0000  61 62 63 fe 83 bf bf bf  bf 82 78 79 7a           abc..... ..xyz

› perl -MEncode -lne'
    # replace junk with empty string
    my $line = decode "UTF-8", $_, sub { "" };
    print encode "UTF-8", $line;
' < nonunicodefile
abcxyz
```